# Simple HTML DOM Parser error handling

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using SimpleHTMLDOM Parser to scape a website and I would like to know if there's any error handling method. For example, if the link is broken there is no use to advance in the code and search the document.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
{
  if(empty($element->href))
  {
    continue; //will skip <a> without href
  }

  echo $element->href . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

a loop and continue?